# grails checking first radio button

Tags: grails, gsp

I've created a `<g:each` in my gsp nested with the following radio button.

```
<input type="radio" value="${productQuantityInstance?.quantity}" 
    name="quantity" id="quantity_${productQuantityInstance?.quantity}" 
    ${productInstance?.productQuantities.toArray()[0].quantity.equals(productQuantityInstance?.quantity) ? 'checked="checked"' : ''}>
```

I'm wondering if this is the best way to go about selecting the first radio button?

I'm aware of the grails radioGroup, but it won't work for me in my application.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1636174/grails-testing-for-the-first-element-in-a-set-using-gsp-each looks very similar to your request

Comment: Looks like there's a better solution, thanks